Number of vector of length $n$ over ${A,C,T,G}$ that do not have $k$ consecutive $A$'s
In this problem, $k$ is a constant, and we need to find a recursive function that depends only on $n$, i,e $f(n)$.
Here is my (wrong) solution:
Say there's a valid vector of length $n$. Let's separate to distinct cases:

If there a $k-1$ $A$'s at the end, then the $k$'th letter from the end is not $A$, but one of $C,T,G$. Therefore, i'm left with a valid vector of length $n-k$, and 3 options to for the last $k$ letters, so: $3f(n-k)$.
If there aren't $k-1$ $A$'s at the end, then there are $4^{k-1} -1$ options for the last $k-1$ letters (all but the $A$'s vector). I'm left with a valid vector of length $n-(k-1)$, so I get: $(4^{k-1}-1)f(n-(k-1))$.

Summing these up according to the rule of sum: $$f(n)=3f(n-k)+(4^{k-1}-1)f(n-(k-1))$$ But this solution is incorrect, and I know it because I wrote some Python code to find the solution using my formula, and bruteforcefully. For example, for $k=3,n=4$, I got $252$ instead of $249$ (which is the answer, can be confirmed by hand as well) which means I am somewhere overcounting. But I do not know where, and would like some help identifying the problem in my solution.
Please, anyone who answers this question, don't just write the answer. The main thing I need help with is identifying the problem in my solution, this will give me much more value. Thanks.

Suppose there is not a string of consecutive A's of length $k-1$ at the end, so you find such strings in $4^{k-1}-1$ ways. But what if the first few letters of this string, coupled with some A's at the end of the string of length $n-k$ give more than $k$ A's? That is, your string looks like ($k=3$)
$$\underbrace{ACTAG\ldots GAA}{n-k}\ \ \ \underbrace{AT}{k-1}$$

See also this answer.

The issue with your solution is that it counts the vector $AAAC$ as valid, since it falls into the second case and $AA$ is valid.
Here's a general hint for troubleshooting this kind of problem: modify your algorithm slightly so that instead of computing a number of vectors, it computes a set of vectors. This should be easy enough in a language like Python or Haskell. Then you can filter the resulting set for vectors that don't match your constraints and figure out what's wrong.
import Control.Monad
import Data.List

data Nucleotide = A | T | C | G deriving (Show, Eq)

atcg = [A, T, C, G]
tcg = [T, C, G]

f :: Int -> Int -> [[Nucleotide]]
f k n
  | n < k = replicateM n atcg
  | otherwise =  [p <> [x] <> replicate (k - 1) A | p <- f k (n - k), x <- tcg]
              <> [p <> s | p <- f k (n - k + 1), s <- replicateM (k - 1) atcg, s /= replicate (k - 1) A]

main = do
  let f34 = f 3 4
  print $ length f34 -- 252
  print $ filter (replicate 3 A `isInfixOf`) f34 -- [[A,A,A,T],[A,A,A,C],[A,A,A,G]]

from itertools import product

def f(k, n):
    if n < k:
        return [''.join(s) for s in product('ATCG', repeat=n)]
    else:
        a = [p + x + 'A' * (k - 1) for p in f(k, n - k) for x in 'TCG']
        b = [p + ''.join(s) for p in f(k, n - k + 1) for s in product('ATCG', repeat=k-1) if ''.join(s) != 'A' * (k - 1)]
        return a + b

s = f(3, 4)
print(len(s))
print([i for i in s if 'A' * 3 in i])


But I am assuming a valid vector of length $n$. $AAAC$ is not a valid vector of length $n$ to start with.

And yet your algorithm produces $AAAC$. It sounds like you're reasoning backwards: you don't count a set by assuming you have an element given, you count a set by producing a finite enumeration of its elements.

Do you mind writing this in python?

My Python isn't great but here you go.
