place letters(A B C D) in N places, with repetition such that the letter A doesnt appear K consecutive times
i need find a recursive function for :
place letters(A B C D) in N places, with repetition such that the letter A doesnt appear K consecutive times.
K is given and known to be K>=2.
example for n=4 , k=2 :
AABA is wrong !
ABAC is fine.
what i tried:
look at the first letter , if its not A , then there is 3*f(n-1) options .
if it is A , then i will take the f(n-1) options and subtract all the vectors where A appear
(K-1) times.
to calculate this i fix the first k-1 letters (in the f(n-1**)** ) to be A ,
then chose the letter in postion k+1 (right after the k total A that appeared) - 3 options . then what is left is calculate f(n-k-1) .
so in total i got  : f(n) =4f(n)-3f(n-k-1).
the problem is when i try to see if this function works, i fail .
is there a problem in my solving ?
edited: i did mistake in calculation, the answer is right .

Any such word would have to begin with one of $X, AX, \cdots, A^{k-1}X$ where $X$ is any letter besides $A$.  So you can get a recursive solution as a sum.

Sounds like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4947502/number-of-vector-of-length-n-over-a-c-t-g-that-do-not-have-k-consecutive again. Your definition of $f(n)$ uses $f(n)$: this can't possibly work. (Also, please use MathJax formatting.)

Extending and moderately altering the comment of lulu:
Define $~g(n)~$ as the enumeration of all $~n$-length sequences that contain no occurrence of $~k~$ consecutive A's.
Then, define $~g(n,r)~$ as the enumeration of all $~n$-length sequences that :

end  with XA...A, where the sequence ends with $~r~$ consecutive A's, with $~r \in ~\{0,1,\cdots,k-1\}.~$

contain no occurrence of $~k~$ consecutive A's.


Then you have the recurrence formulas

$g(n) = g(n,0) + g(n,1) + \cdots + g(n,k-1).~$

$g(n+1,0) = 3 \times g(n).~$ 
That is, you start with any satisfying $~n$-length sequence and append one of the characters B,C, or D to the end of the sequence.

$g(n+1,r) = g(n,r-1) ~: ~r \in \{1,2,\cdots,k-1\}.~$ 
That is, you start with any satisfying $~n$-length sequence that ends in exactly $~(r-1)~$ A's, and specifically append an A to the end of the sequence.



A systematic approach with a practical notation is given here, which helps to derive recurrence relations of this type.
We count the number $a_n$ of valid strings of length $n$ from the set $\{A,B,C,D\}$, i.e. strings which do not contain runs of $A$ of length $k$, denoted as $A^k$. We do so   by partitioning  them according to their matching length with the initial parts of   the  bad string $A^k$.
We consider
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a_n=a^{[\emptyset]}_n+a^{[A]}_n+a^{[A^2]}_n+\cdots+a^{[A^{k-1}]}_n}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

The  number $a^{[\emptyset]}_n$ counts the valid strings of  length  $n$   which do not start with the   rightmost character  of  the       bad   word $A^k$,  i.e.  start  with $B, C$ or $D$.

The  number $a^{[A^j]}_n$, where $1\leq j\leq k-1$ counts the valid strings of length  $n$  which do  start with a run of $A$ of length $j$ (and with no greater length).


We  get a    relationship  between valid strings of length $n$  with  those of length  $n+1$  as follows:

If a word counted  by $a^{[\emptyset]}_n$ is appended by $B, C$ or $D$ from the left it contributes to $a^{[\emptyset]}_{n+1}$. If it is appended by $A$ from the left it contributes to $a^{[A]}_{n+1}$.

If a word counted  by $a^{[A^{j}]}_n, 1\leq j < k$ is appended by $B, C$ or $D$ from the left it contributes to $a^{[\emptyset]}_{n+1}$. If it is appended by $A$ from the left it contributes to $a^{[A^{j+1}]}_{n+1}$.

If a word counted  by $a^{[A^{k-1}]}_n$ is appended by $B, C$ or $D$ from the left it contributes to $a^{[\emptyset]}_{n+1}$. Appending from the left by $A$  is not allowed since then we have an invalid string starting with $A^k$.


This relationship can be written as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a^{[\emptyset]}_{n+1}}&\color{blue}{=3a^{[\emptyset]}_{n}+3a^{[A]}_{n}
+\cdots+3a^{[A^{k-1}]}_{n}}\tag{2}\\
\color{blue}{a^{[A]}_{n+1}}&\color{blue}{=a^{[\emptyset]}_n}\tag{3.1}\\
\color{blue}{a^{[A^2]}_{n+1}}&\color{blue}{=a^{[A]}_n}\tag{3.2}\\
\vdots\\
\color{blue}{a^{[A^{k-1}]}_{n+1}}&\color{blue}{=a^{[A^{k-2}]}_n}\tag{3.k-1}\\
\end{align*}
We can now derive a recurrence relation from (1),(2),(3.1) - (3.k-1):

We obtain for $n\geq k$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a_{n+1}}&=a^{[\emptyset]}_{n+1}+a^{[A]}_{n+1}+\cdots
+a^{[A^{k-1}]}_{n+1}\tag{$ \to\ $(1)}\\
&=\left(3a^{[\emptyset]}_{n}+3a^{[A]}_{n}+\cdots+3a^{[A^{k-1}]}_{n}\right)\tag{$\to\ $(2)}\\
&\qquad+a^{[\emptyset]}_{n}+a^{[A]}_{n}+\cdots+a^{[A^{k-2}]}_{n}\tag{$\to\ $(3.1) - (3.k-1)}\\
&=4a_{n}-a^{[A^{k-1}]}_{n}\tag{$ \to\ $ (1)}\\
&=4a_{n}-a^{[A^{k-2}]}_{n-1}\tag{$ \to\ $(3.k-1)}\\
&=4a_{n}-a^{[A^{k-3}]}_{n-2}\tag{$ \to\ $(3.k-2)}\\
&\qquad\quad\vdots\\
&=4a_{n}-a^{[A]}_{n-k+2}\tag{$ \to\ $(3.2)}\\
&=4a_{n}-a^{[\emptyset]}_{n-k+1}\tag{$ \to\ $(3.1)}\\
&=4a_{n}-\left(3a^{[\emptyset]}_{n-k}+3a^{[A]}_{n-k}
+\cdots+3a^{[A^{k-1}]}_{n-k}\right)\tag{$ \to\ $(2)}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=4a_n-3a_{n-k}}\tag{$\to (1)$}
\end{align*}

